# search and Replace in specific pattern using VIM

Tags: vim

Input  : -

```
{NSM_QOS_DEFAULT_COS_OVERRIDE_NOT_CONFIGURED,  "%% nsm_qos_default_cos_override_not_configured"},
{NSM_QOS_COS_SETTING_FAILED,      "%% nsm_qos_cos_setting_failed"},
{NSM_QOS_ACCESS_GROUP_ALREADY_ATTACHED_TO_CLASS_MAP,    "%% nsm_qos_access_group_already_attached_to_class_map"},
```

Output should be : -

```
  {NSM_QOS_DEFAULT_COS_OVERRIDE_NOT_CONFIGURED,  "%% nsm qos default cos override not configured"},
{NSM_QOS_COS_SETTING_FAILED,      "%% nsm qos cos setting failed"},
{NSM_QOS_ACCESS_GROUP_ALREADY_ATTACHED_TO_CLASS_MAP,    "%% nsm qos access group already attached to class map"},
```

I tried a search pattern :-

```
%s/\l_\l/\l \l/g
```

but output is not proper , it's replacing(character also which i don't want) like this :

```
before : - nsm_qos
after : - nm os     (but i need like this -->  nsm qos )
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess this should work for you:

```
%s/\v([a-z])_([a-z])/\1 \2/g  
"Note, this requires the `ignorecase` option not set.
```

or

```
%s/\v(\l)_(\l)/\1 \2/g
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that in the command:

```
:%s/\l_\l/\l \l/g
```

you are not actually storing the value of the letters on either side of `_`, so you're losing them as part of the search+replace.

In fact, when *replacing* values in vim, `\l` [has a special meaning](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Changing_case_with_regular_expressions): "Make the first letter of the following word lower-case" - which is clearly not what you intended!

There are a few ways this can be solved. The simplest is to store both letters in capture groups, and use these values in the replace section (`\1` and `\2` respectively):

```
:%s/\(\l\)_\(\l\)/\1 \2/g
```

A slightly simpler way of writing this is to use vim's [very magic](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html) modifier: `\v` - which eliminates the need for most of those ugly back-slashes:

```
:%s/\v(\l)_(\l)/\1 \2/g
```

Or, an alternative approach is to use vim's lookbehind/lookahead functionality. For example, you can use `\zs` and `\ze` to mark the start/end of the matched string respectively, and do the following:

```
:%s/\l\zs_\ze\l/ /g
```

In this case, the letters on either side of `_` are no longer included in the search - and therefore do not get replaced. (So, we do not need to store them in a variable.)